NP-Hardness of a Modified Multiple Knapsack Problem
I have $n$ knapsacks, each with a distinct volume capacity denoted as $c_j$. Additionally, there are $m$ items, each with a specified volume $v_i$, where the volume of an item is also equal to its value (i.e., its value is $v_i$). The goal is to maximize the total value received, framing this initially as an instance of the Multiple Knapsack Problem.
Suppose now, however, that we allow items to be placed fractionally in knapsacks. Crucially though, suppose we have the restriction that if an item is placed fractionally in one knapsack, no fraction of it can be placed in any other knapsack. In other words, if we place a fraction $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ of item $i$ in knapsack $j$, then the fraction of item $i$ placed in every other knapsack $\{ 1, 2, \dots, n \} \setminus \{ j \}$ must be 0.
I suspect this problem is NP-hard but am having difficulty proving it. Attempts to reduce from the Multiple Knapsack Problem and the Multiple Subset Sum Problem have not been successful, as these problems do not incorporate the fractional twist present in my problem.
Is there a well-known computational problem this variant is equivalent to, or a method to demonstrate that it is NP-hard?
